# Remote Logging complete Logcat (Android) (React Native : Android)

Tags: android, react-native

How to get complete logcat from remote users phone?

I came across BUGFENDER and www.REMOTELOGCAT.com ... (didnt use yet.)

I need advice what professionals use for remote logging? 
What is the industry standard?

How can I get complete logcat from my client's phone living in another country?

In iOS it gets saved in the phone itself so client can email that log file but whats the solution in android ?

P.S by 'complete logcat' i mean COMPLETE logcat rather than specified logs in code like log.e("some exception occured") as in crashlytics...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get the full logcat in Android.

What I can answer is that I'm professional and I use Bugfender for remote logging in iOS and React Native and I know many colleagues using Bufender for Android as well.